# Is it possible to retreive more details from Facebook Graph API regarding cities for a page?

Tags: json, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I'm developing a tool in python which exports Facebook KPIs daily.

So far so good, I managed to get it to work and it is working fine.
But now my customer requested even more details for the cities returned by the page insights API.

For example:
Facebook returns a JSON like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_impressions_by_city_unique",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "Arcole, Italy": 1,
            "Brentino Belluno, Italy": 2,
            "Bolzano, Italy": 2,
            "Naples, Italy": 1,
            "Padua, Italy": 1,
            "Rome, Italy": 1,
            ...
          },
          "end_time": "2019-05-13T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Daily Reach by City",
      "description": "Daily: Total Page Reach by user city. (Unique Users)",
      "id": "***"
    }
  ]
}
```

The real problem is that in Italy there are some cities with the same name but different postal code (CAP in italian). That translates into potentials wrong attributions. So finally back to my question...

Can I get more information from these APIs such as the postal code or the Region? I could not find anything

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Comment: No, I don’t see how that would be possible. There are no additional parameters to request more detailed info on the cities, and no ids by which any Graph API object potentially holding more info could be looked up either.

Comment: _“in Italy there are some cities with the same name but different postal code”_ - are those different cities to begin with, or are those just _one_ city, that has different areas with individual postal codes? If the latter, then your actual question would rather be, can I get this kind of data with a postal code granularity, and the answer is simply, No.

Comment: @04FS I try to make a better example. Let's assume we have a city named A in the Region "Emilia-Romagna". In another region, for example, "Lombardia" we have another city named "A". Facebook just returns A, Italy without other information. Anyway, I would say that you answered my question. Thank you